# How to label the voronoi diagram D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, voronoi

I have done some Voronoi Diagram in d3, however I'm unsure of how to label the Voronoi Diagram.

This is the Voronoi diagram I have done.

[image]

What I want to do will be something like this

[image]

Below is the Json file that the Voronoi Diagram is reading.

```
{
"name": "flare",
"children": [
 {
  "name": "analytics"
 },
 {
  "name": "animate"
 },
 {
  "name": "data"
 },
 {
  "name": "display"
 },
 {
  "name": "flex"
 },
 {
  "name": "physics"
 },
 {
  "name": "query"
 },
 {
  "name": "scale"
 },
 {
  "name": "util","size":10
 },
 {
  "name": "vis"
 }
]
}
```

Comment: pls share your code instead of sharing images. though they help to understand. Still, code is the most important part, at least show us what you tried by sharing your code

Comment: As there are too many line of codes, so I decided to upload to my google drive

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rnj4FktvlAY2BLbYhCJ04yuYg4V6CgSY?usp=sharing

Comment: how to draw a Voronoi without any 2D locations?

Comment: where is `PowerDiagram.js`?

Comment: which d3v3 example did you modify?

Comment: Good luck finding someone to wade through that wall of code to answer your question.  You should really create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @rioV8 I just uploaded the PowerDiagram.js

Comment: the colors and text is not your biggest problem, the software crashes with `twin is null` (ConvexHull.js) and sometimes it generates `NaN` for the voronoi locations